# Cloudkit: CKNotificationInfo badge value never decrease

Tags: iphone, ipad, icloud, cloudkit, cknotification

I set subscription notifications for cloudkit. Here is my code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"TRUEPREDICATE"];
    CKSubscription *subscription = [[CKSubscription alloc]
                                    initWithRecordType:recordType
                                    predicate:predicate
                                    options:CKSubscriptionOptionsFiresOnRecordCreation];
    CKNotificationInfo *notificationInfo = [CKNotificationInfo new];
    notificationInfo.alertLocalizationKey =@"New record in cloudKit";
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = YES;
    notificationInfo.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = YES;
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo;
    CKContainer *container = [CKContainer defaultContainer];
    CKDatabase *publicDatabase = [container publicCloudDatabase];
    [publicDatabase saveSubscription:subscription
                   completionHandler:^(CKSubscription *subscription, NSError *error) {
                       if (!error)
                       {
                           NSLog(@"no error");
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           NSLog(@"error%@", error);
                       }

                       }];
```

and works just fine. The problem is the badges, they seem like cloudKit doesn't reset the badge number and the keep increasing even when I set the badge count to zero.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    application.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
}
```

When the app received a new notification goes from 0 to 5 (and every new notification increase by 1, the next time would be 6)

Any of you knows how keep track of the right count of badges from cloudkit (in Objective-C )

Comment: possible duplicate of [CloudKit won't reset my badge count to 0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120070/cloudkit-wont-reset-my-badge-count-to-0)

Answer (score 9):

This is a duplicate of [CloudKit won't reset my badge count to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120070/cloudkit-wont-reset-my-badge-count-to-0)

The answer there was:
You need to do a CKModifyBadgeOperation after processing your notifications.

Here is my Swift function which I call after marking all the notifications as read. I add the operation to the defaultContainer instead of just starting it - I wonder does that make any difference.

```
func resetBadgeCounter() {
    let badgeResetOperation = CKModifyBadgeOperation(badgeValue: 0)
    badgeResetOperation.modifyBadgeCompletionBlock = { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            println("Error resetting badge: \(error)")
        }
        else {
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        }
    }
    CKContainer.defaultContainer().addOperation(badgeResetOperation)
}
```

Comment: My proyect is objective-c. Can you post the equivalent in objective-c ?

Comment: This is good, but CKModifyBadgeOperation is now deprecated. What do we do now?

Comment: @OwenGodfrey I'm asking the same thing two years later   - have you found a solution to this?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47542005/ckmodifybadgeoperation-is-deprecated-in-ios-11-anyone-know-an-alternative-appro

Answer (score 1):

This will help.

```
CKModifyBadgeOperation *badgeResetOperation = [[CKModifyBadgeOperation alloc] initWithBadgeValue:0];
[badgeResetOperation setModifyBadgeCompletionBlock:^(NSError * operationError) {
    if (!operationError) {
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
    }
}];
[[CKContainer defaultContainer] addOperation:badgeResetOperation];
```