# CKModifyBadgeOperation is deprecated in iOS 11. Anyone know an alternative approach?

Tags: ios11, cloudkit, swift4, badge, cknotification

I have searched, and I cannot find an example. I have also tried adapting this code (recommended elsewhere ([CloudKit won't reset my badge count to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120070/cloudkit-wont-reset-my-badge-count-to-0)):

```
func resetBadgeCounter() {
    let badgeResetOperation = CKModifyBadgeOperation(badgeValue: 0)
    badgeResetOperation.modifyBadgeCompletionBlock = { (error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print("Error resetting badge: \(String(describing: error))")
        }
        else {
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0
        }
    }
    CKContainer.default().add(badgeResetOperation)
}
```

This works for now, but is no longer supported, and may go away soon.

I thought perhaps I should use a CKModfyRecordsOperation or some other CKDatabaseOperation, but I can't even guess how.

Comment: Any news on this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's probably best to just track the items you are counting and set the app badge count yourself. I reference a local database that has my items in it, and I return the total and set my app badge accordingly.

Comment: This doesn't work for remote notifications.  It works locally but the next time a remote notification comes in the badge number becomes 2 not 1.

Comment: This remains a real problem.    Is there any work-around?

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps someone as there doesn't seem to be another solution/workaround to this.

1. Create a *Notification Service Extension* (`UNNotificationServiceExtension`) for your app. It is fairly straightforward and is described in detail in [Modifying Content in Newly Delivered Notifications](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications). You might already have one, if you do any kind of processing on incoming notifications.
2. Within the extension, you typically do all the processing of the notification in `override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`. The `request` comes with the `content` of the notification, which includes the **badge number**. You can then modify that and pass on to the `contentHandler` to be displayed. (*If you are unsure how to do this, check the [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/modifying_content_in_newly_delivered_notifications) above; it has detailed instructions and code.*)
3. To keep track and reset the badge number when needed, you need to take advantage of an app group (e.g. `group.com.tzatziki`). This way you can share data between the app and the extension. Creating an app group in Xcode can be done by adding the relevant *capability* and is explained in [App Extension Programming Guide: Handling Common Scenarios](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH21-SW1).
4. Use a storage mechanism (within the app group) to keep track of the badge count, e.g. `UserDefaults`, and use it in the extension to update the badge count. In the aforementioned `override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void)`, you could write something like this:

   ```
   let badgeNumber = UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.com.tzatziki")?.value(forKey: "badgeNumber") as? NSNumber ?? NSNumber(integerLiteral: 0)
   let badgeNumberInt = badgeNumber.intValue + 1
   notificationContent.badge = NSNumber(value: badgeNumberInt)
   UserDefaults(suiteName: "group.io.prata")?.setValue(notificationContent.badge, forKey: "badgeNumber")
   ```

where `notificationContent` is an instance of `UNMutableNotificationContent`, originating from `request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent`

5. Now, the only thing left to do is to reset the badge count in your app, in the shared `UserDefaults` and in `UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber`.

Cheers!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work.  In CloudKit the system keeps a count of the number of notifications that it has sent. If you reset it on the device then the next time CloudKit sends a notification the badge goes back to its old number plus one.

Is there any work-around?

Comment: It was reported here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-reset-badge-value-of-cloudkit-remote-notification-on-ios-ipados-15-46726a435599 that Apple is aware of the need to keep supporting CKModifyBadgeOperation

Answer (score 0):

It was reported here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-reset-badge-value-of-cloudkit-remote-notification-on-ios-ipados-15-46726a435599 that Apple is aware that they need to maintain CKModifyBadgeOperation until they come up with a replacement API.  There is no other solution to this problem because CloudKit resets the badge number whenever it pushes a new notification.